# ERROR: Failed to spawn fakeroot worker to run /PATH_TO_THIS/example_0.1.bb:do_install: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: c, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to compile a c code and install it using yocto. it is successfully compiled using do_compile.

I tried to install using `do_install`, it is giving bellow error.

> ERROR: Failed to spawn fakeroot worker to run /PATH_TO_THIS/example_0.1.bb:do_install: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Please find my bb file below

```
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}   /MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://sample.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc sample.c -o test_example
}

do_install() {
     install -d ${D}${bindir}
     install -m 0755 test_example ${D}${bindir}
 }
```

Comment: How exactly are you running this? Are you by chance using bitbake's -b option?

Comment: Hi bluelightning, Yes bitbake -b /*path*/example_0.1.bb

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment above that you are using -b - that is almost certainly the cause of this issue. When you use -b bitbake will print this warning:

> WARNING: Buildfile specified, dependencies will not be handled. If this is not what you want, do not use -b / --buildfile.

One of the dependencies that you may be missing is the fakeroot program (pseudo). Using -b is likely preventing that from being built.

Instead of using -b, you should put the recipe into a place bitbake can find it (to test, could be meta/recipes-extended/example, but when you do it properly you should create your own layer and put it there). Then you can just build it like any other recipe:

```
bitbake example
```